# how to write RewriteCond for a url with subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, rewritecond, robots.txt

I am trying to ban some bots by writing a RewriteCond rule in htaccess file. Is the following ruleset correct if I add the following:

```
## block traffic from particular referrers
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www\.)?example-subdomain.parent.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www\.)?example-2-domain.net [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) - [F]
```

As you see I wish to ban by domain name and not by IP address. Is it OK if I remove the (www.) part?

Update: My question is mainly related to RewriteCond correct syntax for the urls.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You could replace "[http://(www\.)](http://(www%5C.))?" with ".*" as long as you don't expect that domain name to appear elsewhere in legitimate referer strings.  I'd also suggest putting .* after the .com or .net in case any slashes or paths get tacked on there.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the parant domain and want to block it and all of its sub-domains:

```
^https?://([^.]+\.)*exampledomain\.com
```